# OpenMP tasks - why a segmentation fault appears for larger number of iterations ~10k?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openmp

I am using the following code for finding the sum of the elements of an array using OpenMP tasks construct.
The code is yielding the correct results till **`n = 10000`**.

But beyond that, I am getting a segmentation fault. Using **`gdb`**, I found that the fault occurs in one of the recursive calls to `reduce()`. There is no problem with the input array allocation, and I have verified that.

Does anyone have any suggestion on what the problem might be?

```
int reduce (int *arr, unsigned long int n)
{   
    int x;
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {   
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {   
            #pragma omp task shared(x)
            x = reduce(arr, n-1) + arr[n-1];
            #pragma omp taskwait
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: how is `n` going to be `< 0` when it's `unsigned`?

Comment: increase your stack size and have a look at `OMP_STACKSIZE`

Comment: Please format your code. This is so needlessly ugly, it hurts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are encountering a "stack overflow" via the recursion depth of function calls. Remember that most openmp pragmas generate functions themselves, which are probably interfering with the tail-recursion optimization.

If you run via valgrind, it should warn you about overflowing the stack.

Comment: If using GCC or Clang, it is also possible to compile and link with `-fsanitize=address`. It will instrument the program and catch similar problems than valgrind, but a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

dlasalle is correct about the actual error.

However, there are two more fundamental issues on how you use OpenMP tasks. You spawn a parallel region within each recursive call. This means you use nested parallel regions. By default nested parallelism is disabled in OpenMP, and it doesn't make sense here. You want all tasks you spawn during the recursion to be executed by the same pool of threads. To do that, you have to move the `parallel`/`single` outside of the recursion, e.g.

```
int reduce_par(int* arr, unsigned long int n)
{
    int x;
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    #pragma omp task shared(x)
    x = reduce_par(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
    #pragma omp taskwait
    return x;
}

int reduce(int* arr, unsigned long int n)
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {
            reduce_par(arr, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Even if this wouldn't segfault, and even if you had infinite amount of cores, with infinite memory bandwidth and no thread creation overhead, this still woudn't provide any performance benefit from the parallelization. To figure this out, draw the graph of tasks and their operations and add the dependencies. Try to arrange nodes of the graph in a time axis respecting the task dependencies and see if anything at all can be computed in parallel.

The right solution for a parallel summation is a `parallel for` worksharing construct with a `reduce` clause. And if you had to use tasks, you need to use divide and conquer, e.g. spawn two tasks for two halves of the array. And to get reasonable performance you have to stop the task creation / recursion at some minimal workload size in order to keep the overhead manageable.